# Change the default save location for Excel 2016

Tags: ms-office

I want to change the default save location for Excel files (Office Mac 2016), but cannot find anywhere to do it (unlike Word).

Comment: purplemac's solution works, clumsy as it is @Sparker - do not see "file/options" in my navigation should really be in Preferences/Save....

Answer (score 1):

1. In Excel, navigate to File|Options|Save.
2. Check "Save to Computer by default"
3. Enter "Default local file location"

Answer (score 0):

1. Save an Excel file in the folder you wish to set as default
2. Select "Open" from the File menu
3. In the green vertical banner, select "Open"
4. Navigate to the folder
5. Select and open an Excel file from that folder

The folder will now be the default save location.

This seems clumsy and there may be another way, but it seems this unhelpful opacity is a feature of Office 2016.